# PHPExcel - set cell format to "Date (short)" and insert date from string

Tags: excel-2007, cell, phpexcel, date-formatting

I have an .xlsx file where cells of column C have format `Date (short)`. In the cells is visible a date in this format: `30.1.2017`.

If you switch the cells format to `General` you will see numbers like this: 42765.

I need to insert new line, set format Date (short) on C cell of new column and insert the date that I have in string. Cannot find approriate examples. How could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

MS Excel stores dates as a serialized timestamp value, a count of the number of days since 1st January 1900 (or 1st January 1904 if created on a Mac)... that's what your `42765` value is.

PHPExcel provides a number of functions for date handling, which can be found in the `PHPExcel_Shared_Date` class.

You can convert a unix timestamp or a PHP DateTime object to an MS Excel serialized timestamp using the `PHPToExcel()` method. If you have a string value for your date, then convert it to a PHP DateTime object first.
Then you can set the cell value to the resulting timestamp value, and apply a number format mask to tell Excel how that date should be displayed. The [02types.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/02types.php) example in the [Examples](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/tree/1.8/Examples) folder demonstrates this:

```
$dateTimeNow = time();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->setCellValue('C9', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel( $dateTimeNow ));
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('C9')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2);
```

And it is also explained in the [PHPExcel Documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md#setting-a-date-andor-time-value-in-a-cell)